# Properly connecting a guitar to audio interface with a pedal

Tags: audio-recording, audio-interfaces, guitar, digital, computer

I want to preface this that I'm a total noob and though some answers are similar to my question here, I wasn't sure I understood them.

I've purchased Focusrite Scarlett Solo (3rd Gen) USB Audio Interface to hook up to my computer.

Now, what I'm curious about, is if I have a few pedals for the guitar. What exactly is the procedure for hooking those up? It's all well and good to process the signal in the software, but what happens if I have a pedal like:

guitar -> pedal -> interface -> computer ?

Is that the appropriate way of doing that?

EDIT: I should clarify that what I basically want is to experiment with a variety of effects but am concerned about latency (hasn't seemed to be an issue so far with a 3/4 to USB even) as well as not properly putting the pedal in the chain so to speak (guitar 3/4 to USB is extremely noisy - I wonder if that's just the nature of the cord or cheap guitar electronics)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Link them up exactly as you would with a guitar amp -
guitar > pedals > amp/Scarlett.

Analog effects pedals don't have latency. Only once you go through the computer will you see any latency at all.
If the Scarlett has a 'through' setting that avoids going through the computer before it can send to headphones/monitors, then you can avoid that too.

Comment: Thank you. Silly folllow up - does it matter the quality of the 3/4 cord? Is there different types?

Comment: Cables come in many qualities, but you hit 'acceptable' really quite cheaply. If you're paying more than about $£€ 20 for a guitar cable, you're not going to get much better. tbh, I have no idea what a 3/4 cord is. Standard guitar jacks are 6.35mm, commonly called quarter inch jacks.

Comment: that's the ones I was talking about - the normal guitar ones. 1/4 - not 3/4.